# How to add both integer field and choices in a single attribute of a model class in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

I want to add both choices of `days and hours` in my `assigned_time` field, along with adding how many `days` or how many `hours`.
Here is what I tried that doesn't work.
**Here is my model.py**

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    DAYS= 'D'
    HOURS = 'H'
    STATUS= [
        ('D', 'Days'),
        ('H', 'Hours')
    ]
    employee= models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date= models.DateField(verbose_name='Date')
    designation=models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    projects= models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='Project Name')
    assigned_time= models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Assigned Hours/days', choices=STATUS, default=DAYS)
    time_spent=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Spent Hours/Days', choices=STATUS, default=DAYS)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Description')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.employee.user.first_name} {self.employee.user.last_name} {self.project}'
```

Check for `assigned_time` or `time_spent` field. I want to do the same thing on both as I explained above.

Here is my admin.py

```
@admin.register(Timesheet)
class TimesheetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('first_name', 'last_name', 'date', 'assigned_time', 'projects', 'time_spent', 'description', 'designation_name')

    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.employee.user.first_name

    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.employee.user.last_name

    def designation_name(self, obj):
        return obj.designation.designation_name
```

Here is the image of what I am getting

[image]

**What should I do to add both things in a single field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create another field for type of time. You cannot have both in the same field. Even if it would be not readable for some reasons. I suggest such solution:

Add another field of type and use `CHOICES` there:

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    STATUS = [
        ('D', 'Days'),
        ('H', 'Hours')
    ]

    ...
    time_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Type of time', choices=STATUS, default=STATUS[0], max_length=10)
    assigned_time = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Assigned time', default=0)
    time_spent = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Spent time', default=0)
    ...
```

I also corrected your attempt for choices. It was not working, cause `IntegerField` cannot accept `string` values.

UPDATE:
If you really need have it in one field, you can use `IntegerField` choices like that:

```
STATUS = [
    (1, '1 Hour'),
    (2, '2 Hours'),
    (3, '3 Hours'),
    ...
    (1, '1 Day'),
    (2, '2 Days'),
    (3, '3 Days'),
    ...
]

# or comprehensions will give us same result with less code

STATUS = [
(i, f'{i} Days') for i in range(1, 31)
]

[STATUS.append((i, f'{i} Hours')) for i in range(1, 25)]
```

But remember, that first value of the tuple has to fit `Field` type.

Comment: Comprehension is giving me this error
`ERRORS:
core.Timesheet.assigned_time: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
core.Timesheet.time_spent: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.`
I think its because of what you said in the last  **the first value of the tuple has to fit field type** What does it mean?

Comment: Sorry, missed one closing bracket inside the second one. It actually might not need double brackets in `append` method. But for now I leave that.

Comment: First value of tuple is the value that actually goes to database. It means it has to be the same type as the `Field` is expecting. So for `IntegerField` first value in tuple has to be `Integer`. Second value is for human readable reasons.